# Piping two greps doesn't want to work

Tags: linux, bash

So, I have a script with these lines:

```
read -p "Give me the number: " cardNo
echo $cardNo
t1=$(grep ^$cardNo TestFile.txt | grep " V ")
echo $t1
```

and my TestFile.txt has some lines, including this one:

```
0098876634569080 SMITH GEORGE V 25575
```

which is: `Card Number, Surname, Name, Valid/Invalid, Money ammount`.

Anyway, when I run it and give `0098876634569080` as the card number, the second echo returns a blank string. I tried removing the pipe and one of the two greps and it worked as it should. Any input?

Comment: What should be the output @Teo

Comment: @Skynet the whole line.

Comment: Your code works fine as posted.  Are you able to replicate with that *exact* code and input data?

Comment: Yes, I copied and pasted everything here. Could it possibly be something messed up with my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
grep "$cardNo" TestFile.txt | grep " V "
```

Comment: @Teo please try it, I think it will surely solve your problem

Comment: @TeoAlivanoglou remove the `^` and run it again

Comment: No problem @TeoAlivanoglou, we're happy to help you